# Regular Expression: How to Capture a Pattern Possibly Containing a Substring Without Capturing Subsequent Occurrences of the Same Substring

Tags: regex

Out of the following line of text:

```
start - before capture text - tocapture - maybe after capture
```

I have to reliably capture the value "text - tocapture", without dragging along the optional `- maybe after capture` part.

- The space-dash-space pattern in `text - tocapture` may or may not be present. `text - tocapture` may also be a single word or have spaces.
- If `- maybe after capture` is present, it will always start with space-dash-space, then random text.

I need `text - tocapture` to be fully matched whether `- maybe after capture` is present or not.

The best I've come up with is:

```
^start - before capture (.*)( - .*)?$
```

The problem is, it captures everything after "text - tocapture", presumably because it also contains " - ". I've tried some negative lookahead stuff but no luck. See Rubular output below.

[image: First Attempt]

[image: Second Attempt]

Comment: Does `text - tocapture` always contain exactly one dash? If not, how would you tell the different dashes apart?

Comment: @Tim, `text - tocapture` _may_ contain the pattern space-dash-space. ` - maybe after capture` is optional, but if present, will always start with space-dash-space, then some random string. Therefore, my problem is capturing `text - tocapture` in those cases in which it contains space-dash-space AND ` - maybe after capture` is present.

Comment: ... and I'm beginning to think that without further qualifying the last dash, I won't be able to distinguish it from the maybe-present previous dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you need correctly, I think this should do it:

```
^start - before capture (.*? - .*?)( - .*)?$
```

In which `$1` should capture what you need.  In your example, it captures:

```
1.  text - tocapture
2.  - maybe after capture
```

Comment: this indeed matches, but (and I neglected to mention this - editing the question now) the space-dash-space pattern in `text - tocapture` may not be present. When I put it in parens with the ? quantifier, your expression captures on `text` and not `text - tocapture`.

Comment: @UdiBar-On I believe your syntax is ambiguous, in that case.  How can I tell the difference between "start - before capture sometext - and capture this too!" and "start - before capture sometext - but do not capture this!"

Comment: Thanks @femtoArgon, I've come to the same conclusion. Marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal: `.*` captures everything, and your second part is optional.

Your `.*` will therefore capture `text - tocapture - maybe after capture` and leave nothing for the second group. As the quantifier `?` makes it optional, it is perfectly happy with an empty string...

In order for reliably capture what you want, you can use this:

```
^start - before capture ([^-]+-[^-\s]+).*
```

Comment: That won't change anything.

Comment: fge, your edited expression doesn't match on my line of text, nor on the alternative ("start - before capture text - tocapture") which I wish the same expression to match on as well.